# SQL get information from one table based on another's row value and vice versa

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am indexing music download in a MySQL database and am limited to two databases total. I have decided to organize the database like this:

Database:

```
music
>  artist
>>   artistS
>>   artistR
>>   genre
>  album
>>   album
>>   artistS
>>   year
>  song
>>   song
>>   album
>>   artistS
```

I want to know if there is a way to enter one of these values, and get all of the results from all of the tables (e.g. I enter "Blues", I get the artists from the table artist with the "Blues" genre, the albums from that artist because the artist has the genre "Blues", and all of the songs from the albums from the artists because they have the genre "Blues").

Please say so if you need for information or clarification.

Comment: You might want to take a look into `Join` statements http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Artists as primary key in artist table and make it foreign key in Album table and associate with artists column in album table. do same with album column of album table make it primary key and make it foreign key in Song table associated with album column. Then insert data in all tables make sure to enter values in foreign key column same as primary key it is associated with e.g in

**artist table**

```
Artists = ABC (primary key)
ArtsitR = XYZ
Genre = Blues
```

**in Album table**

```
Album = PQR (Primary key)
Artists = ABC (foreign key)Same value as in table artist
Year = 1990
```

**in song table**

```
Song = MNO
Album = PQR  (foreign key)Same value as in table album
Artists = KLM
```

Now use this query

```
Select artist.Artists,artist.Genre, artist.ArtistR, artist.album,Album.Artists,Album.year,
Song.Song,Song.Artists from artist inner join album on album.Artists = artist.Artists
inner join Song on Song.Album = album.Album where artist.Genre = 'Blues'
```

Hope this will help you..